# Idea for resolving implicit includes in C, C++

Tags: c++, c

I've just came up with an idea to solve a problem and wanted to share it. Sorry if too banal.

So, a big C++ project I am reviewing, contains many includes which relies on symbols from other includes but which don't include the required includes. Any slight change in build-procedure results in "missing symbol" failures.

So in order to check all includes for self-containment at once, I search for all *.h, create on the fly a cpp-file which only contains #include -statement with this .h file and try to compile it. At the end I obtain a list of "good" and "bad" include files.
Cool isn't it :-) 
Or is there an easier solution to do it?

Comment: Wouldn't you also catch these if you were to enable implicit declaration warnings and treat warnings as errors in your compiler options?

Comment: -1: Sure, cool idea, but this is not a real question.

Comment: @Andres: Mr. Question Policeman, this is a question, and it asks whether there are better ways to achieve the same

Comment: @Armen Aha, you're right. Vote reversed, but now I think you're a jerk.

Comment: @Andres: No, I am not :) It's just that way too many people just like closing/downvoting questions which do not really deserve it. Sorry if I offended you

Comment: @tdammers: Was not aware of it, thanks! Do you mean -Wimplicit on gcc?

Comment: `for h in *.h{,pp,xx}; do g++ -c -xc++ "$h" -o /dev/null; done`  More or less; it's a good idea to do this implicitly as part of your tests (one test .cpp file per header including the header first) or otherwise make sure you follow it on every build.

Comment: @tdammers: No.  That wouldn't help with the errors he's catching, as implicit declarations aren't the problem.  He's describing dependencies on having certain libraries included before his headers, which are only coincidentally met because of the happenstance of how he includes headers currently.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: Maybe I'm weird but in my career I've had much bigger problems due to circular includes than due to working out the correct include order. As a result, I almost never have headers including other headers. i.e. I intentionally create what I guess you're trying to avoid. :) It means I have to explicitly list lots of headers at the top of my cpp files but that is only a slight, mechanical chore compared to finding and fixing circular dependencies. And I know that if a cpp includes a header and can compile, there cannot be a lurking circular dependency.

Comment: You might be interested in the talk "Implementing Include-What-You-Use using clang" listed at http://www.llvm.org/devmtg/2010-11/ .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If every .cpp file includes it's own header-file first, and then other headers, you'll get this check without using external tools.

This is actually part of [Googles C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Names_and_Order_of_Includes) for the same reason:

> The preferred ordering reduces hidden
>   dependencies. We want every header
>   file to be compilable on its own. The
>   easiest way to achieve this is to make
>   sure that every one of them is the
>   first .h file #included in some .cc.

If you have any header files that does not have a corresponding .cpp-file, you'd have to do something special for them.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I always use this include approach, but couldn't remember and argue the reasons. Now I know! Thank you also for pointing to google style guides!

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use precompiled headers with this style :\

Comment: @Inverse: interesting! I've never used them anyway, what a shame :-(

Answer (score 1):

It's been a good number of years, but I believe Lint does this for you.  And I seem to remember that Lint also tells you when a file is included when a forward declaration would do.

Comment: Ok, thanks! In this customer-code I've even seen many lint pragmas. I should ask them how do they deal with this lint warning. Probably suppressed :-)

Comment: I remember enabling all warnings in Lint 'for a laugh'. 1.2million errors and took most of a weekend to run. It is better to turn off all warnings and turn them on slowly, fix what you need and then progress to the next. I only had interested in 15 or so.